# React setState with promise as a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I received an error when trying to SetState using a Promise as a callback in React. This is likely due to an error on my part and would like some clarification on set State in React. The error message I am receiving is as follows.

ERR: "Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Promise]"

I have refactored my code example below (edit) to try and provide use to others.

```
    this.setState({ value: v }, this.callAsync)

// Async function 

  callAsync = async () => {
    await this.props.foo({
    // Something async-y
   })
 .then(success => console.log(success)
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `this.setState({ value: v }, this.callAsync)`?

Comment: Yes, apologies. Will update!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re the code in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48044601/1):

```
this.setState({ value: v }, this.callAsync())
```

An `async` function **always** returns a promise, which isn't (of course) a callback. In your case, that promise resolves with `undefined` as you haven't done a `return` in your `callAsync`.

If your goal is to call `callAsync` after the state update is complete, then wrap the call in another function, e.g.:

```
this.setState({value: v}, async () => {
    try {
        await this.callAsync();
    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

or

```
this.setState({value: v}, () => {
    this.callAsync().catch(e => {
        // handle error
    });
});
```

Note that it's essential to handle potential errors; otherwise, you'll get unhandled resolution errors if the promise returned by `this.props.foo` is rejected.

---

Re the code in your [modified question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48044601/2):

This is just a simple case of `this` not being what you expect in the callback, as [described in detail in this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). The solution above *also* works for that, conveniently; it's one of the solutions listed by the answers there. And it handles errors correctly, which some of the other answers to that question (using `this.callAsync.bind(this)` for instance) won't.